# Pass ID to bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using squarespaceModal from [this site](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/squarespace-like-modal)

I would like to know if is it possible to pass the id to the code of the modal ?
This is the button who's calling the modal :

```
<div class="center">
    <button id="<?php echo $i; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#squarespaceModal" class="update_pro btn btn-primary center-block">
        update
    </button>
</div>
```

This is the first line of the modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="squarespaceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Assuming all of the first code is inside a PHP page sure, you could pass it, but the real question is why do you want to add it? To make dynamic targets? To differenciate them?

Comment: What you want to do ??

Comment: I want to add information inside placeholders.  I have an array of objects (js) and I want to give the number of the object to add in the placeholder of the input (like name, id...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your button click set the require value into your input fields of modal and then show modal using below code.

```
$(".update_pro").click(function () {
    $('#txtYourTexbBoxWithinModal').val($(this).data('id')); // or something eslse.
    $('#squarespaceModal').modal('show');
});
```

If come across issue of displaying modal then remove

> data-target="#squarespaceModal"

Cheeerssss

Answer (score 2):

That is just a standard [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals) I dont see anything special about it. Therefore you have all the [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events) you would like from the modal.

So you "could" write an event to trap everytime a modal is opened.

```js
$(function() {
   $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="myButton" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Open</button>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is my modal body
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I would like to get the id of the button who called the modal form, posible ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/32jsq6aL/

```js
$('button[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(){
  $($(this).data('target')).attr('btn-id', $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center"> 
  <button id="test 1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#squarespaceModal" class="update_pro btn btn-primary center-block">update</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="squarespaceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

</div>
```

`OnClick` on the `button`, get the `data-target` and attach an attribute `btn-id` as `button id` to the targeted `modal`.

Hope this will help you.